# How to replace getElementsByTagName() By document.getElementsById()

Tags: php, html, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I have this code and I want to get a link of an image stored in a website by its Id but this code use  `getElementsByTagName('')` :

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://example.com/dir/webpage.html');

$dom = new DOMDocument;

@$dom->loadHTML($html);


$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');


foreach ($links as $link){

         echo $link->nodeValue;
    echo $link->getAttribute('href'), '<br>';
}
?>
```

And The HTML is:

```
<a href="/images/image1.png" id="img_1_id">
                            <div class="download"></div>
                        </a>
```

I want to replace `getElementsByTagName('img')` with `document.getElementsByById(img_1_id)`

so the script get the url of the selected image with the id: `img_1_id`

If there another way / code to do this please post it :)

Thank you pros!

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: There's no such function as `getElementsById`. Since IDs should be unique, the function is `getElementById` (no `s`). It returns a single element, not a list of elements, so you don't need a loop.

Comment: @u_mulder the problem is the I want to get the link by ID

Comment: @Barmar , thank you for reply but should I do ?

Comment: @NadineAh This is not a problem, this is a wish.

Comment: @u_mulder so is there another way to get the link by ID from a URL?

Answer (score 1):

`getElementById` returns a single element, you don't need a loop.

```
$link = $dom->getElemebtById('img_1_id');
echo $link->nodeValue;
echo $link->getAttribute('href');
```

BTW, `img` elements don't have an `href` attribute, they have `src`. They also don't have anything in their `nodeValue`, since `<img>` is not a container element.

Comment: the (img) can be in a tag so it has a link when click on it. and the image or the a tag can have an ID.

Comment: my case is to get the link of a div with an ID

Comment: So is `img_1_id` the ID of the image or the link that contains it?

Comment: Maybe you should add the HTML to the question, so we can be sure you're getting the right thing.

Comment: Where is `id="img_1_id"` in the HTML?

Comment: Is that supposed to be a variable, like `$img_1_id = "link1"`?

Comment: sorry :O the id is ( img_1_id ) - Updated @barmar

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the "

```
document.getElementsByById("img_1_id");
```

sou you get the element with id = "img_1_id"

Comment: This answer is Javascript, not PHP.

Comment: Yes! Sorry i did not see that was PHP not JS. :(

But in documentation, in PHP you have to put plic '' too.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domdocument.getelementbyid.php

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://example.com/dir/webpage.html');

$dom = new DOMDocument;

@$dom->loadHTML($html);


$links = $dom->getElementById('img_1_id');


foreach ($links as $link){

         echo $link->nodeValue;
    echo $link->getAttribute('href'), '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: `getElementById` returns single element.